# FILTER(condition OR condition) syntax?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-filter, regex

I am using `FILTER()` to display a value from Sheet 2 where the `Name` columns match.

My problem is where I want:

```
=FILTER(Sheet2!A:F, Sheet2!A:A="Combat Medic" OR Sheet2!A:A="Universal")
```

as `OR` results in an error.

What is the correct syntax?
Must I use a `QUERY()` instead?

Comment: You might also find this useful: [Google Spreadsheets: Filter a range by array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029737/google-spreadsheets-filter-a-range-by-array)

Answer (score 51):

Use the following formula to obtain the query you want.

### Formula

```
=FILTER(A:A;(A:A="Combat Medic")+(A:A="Universal"))
```

### Explained

In the reference it is explained by Ahab that `+` and `*` can be used as boolean expressions, as `OR` and `AND`.

The solution with the `IFERROR` (see revision history) is of no use in this case, unless you want to find a particular string:

```
=FILTER(Sheet2!A:F;IFERROR(FIND("Combat";A:A);0) + IFERROR(FIND("Uni";A:A);0))
```

Here the `IFERROR` returns `0` when nothing is found, causing the formula to still function.

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

I've modified the example file to contain both solutions: **[Filter with Boolean](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdG9sa2thNmhsQURnNDJjaDVwbUM5d2c&usp=sharing)**

### Reference

[Google Product Forum, Boolean Expressions](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/8nStFrjgO5Q/S0ppgEicgcAJ)

Comment: Interesting! Could you elaborate on how `IFERROR(...) + IFERROR(...)`  works?

Comment: where is the documentation that '+' can be used as a boolean OR?

Comment: @ChrisMorris: https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/8nStFrjgO5Q/S0ppgEicgcAJ

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra Thanks Jacob. Is there any official documentation?

Answer (score 2):

```
=FILTER(A:F, REGEXMATCH(A:A, "Combat Medic|Universal"))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=QUERY(A:F, " where A matches 'Combat Medic|Universal'", 0)
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large list of different values that you want to filter by you can JOIN them and use them within a regexmatch.

Instead of:

```
=FILTER(Sheet2!A:F, Sheet2!A:A="Combat Medic" OR Sheet2!A:A="Universal")
```

Try

```
=FILTER(Sheet2!A:F, REGEXMATCH(Sheet2!A:A, JOIN("|", <your_value_range>))
```

**Example:**

In the example below, I have a list of sales people & their sales.
I want to find all sales over €150 by all people who received at least one customer rating of 5.

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).