# Filter rows by a set of numbers from another column

Tags: google-sheets

I have row of six digit numbers where I want to filter rows containing exact numbers set. For example:

```
orderid
154934
154935
154936
154937
154938
154939
154940
```

I want to filter 154935,154937 these numbers exactly. But am not sure how to do that on filter option.

This is just an example. I actually want to do the same from large column.

Comment: Perhaps this answer is of use: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/42433/29140

Comment: [Filter View](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?hl=en) and checking those numbers as options would work as well.

Comment: order status changes everyday like packed, shipped, delivered, etc., for different orders.
if I have to update it in the sheet, I need to filter those exact id but as of now am clicking one by one

Answer (score 0):

> I actually want to do the same from large row

I understand you have a large row of numbers that you would like to filter by. Perhaps your data is in columns A and B, and the cells C1:E1 are occupied by numbers like 154936, 154935, 154940.

Then you can put the following command somewhere:

```
=query(A:B, "select * where A matches '" & join("|", C1:E1) & "'")
```

This does the following:

1. Joins the row of numbers to filter by, using | as a separator.
2. Uses this string `154936|154935|154940` as a regular expression in the [where ... matches](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Where) selector.
3. Selects all columns (within the specified range, A:B) from the rows that matched.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am sorry I confused the question with the word row (I edited it now) but all the data is in one column only. I have all orders in one column and the next day status changes like some orders get shipped, some delivered, some returned. I want to update this status by filter.